# Custom user agent parser

Tags: php, regex, parsing, user-agent

for parsing a user agent I found [ua-parser](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser), this is very powerfull, But I don't want parse browser user agent, I want to parse a custom user agent like this :

```
PaperL Installer (Windows; P; 32bit; Ver 2.0.3; OS: 5.1.2600 SP 3.0 NT; x32c;)
BookL Installer (Windows; B; 64bit; Ver 1.0; OS: 6.1.7601 SP 1.0 NT; x64c;)
```

Now how can I fetch `PaperL` or `BookL` and `Ver` And `x32c` or `x64c` from this agent ?

Comment: What did you try? Following a regular expression tutorial would be a good start.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I try it before, I read http://www.regular-expressions.info/ but I cannot understand what should I do :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could do the thing :) You do not need regex. Also you can get other strings easily.

```
function trim_string($s)
{
    $s = trim($s, ";");
    $s = trim($s, ";)");
    return $s;
}

$string = "PaperL Installer (Windows; P; 32bit; Ver 2.0.3; OS: 5.1.2600 SP 3.0 NT; x32c;)";
$array = explode(" ", $string);

$firstItem = trim_string($array[0]); // return PaperL
$version = trim_string($array[6]); // return 2.0.3
$last = trim_string(end($array)); // return x32c

echo $firstItem. " ". $version. " ". $last; // return PaperL 2.0.3 x32c
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches every component of **your** user agent:

```
(\w+) Installer \(([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+)
```

A more general approach is

```
([^(]+)\(([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+)
```